# Insert cover page into rmarkdown word document

Tags: r, ms-word, r-markdown, officer

I would like to insert a cover page for an Rmarkdown report. This would effectively be a background image and then the title sitting over the top.

I am currently using a word template to provide other themes and settings as laid out in https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_docx.html in conjunction with the officedown package (https://davidgohel.github.io/officedown/index.html) and together these work well. However, I have not seen anywhere the ability to insert cover pages from Rmarkdown. Therefore, is it possible to insert a customisable cover page easily from rmarkdown for use with knitting to word?

If providing a reprex will assist I can do, was hoping to get some direction without it.